# How to prevent a WPF listbox from scrolling past the last item?

Tags: wpf, listbox, scroll

I have a listbox that shows a list of itmes with the same size. The listbox is showing a single column of items with a vertical scroll bar.
Currently, you can scroll past the last item so that there is 1 empty space in the list (there is room for 7 items, and when I scroll to the bottom I see 6 items and an empty sppace for exactly 1 more item).

How can i force the scrollbar not to scroll past the last item?

Comment: It looks like some margin/padding issues on your listboxitems. Can you post some xaml for your listbox and any styles that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this.
This is not a matter of padding and margins, as far as I could see.

What I did is create a behavior for ScrollViewer, where I handle ScroolChanged.

Code for the bahavior:

```
class ScrollViewerRestrictedScrollBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ScrollChanged += AssociatedObject_ScrollChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.VerticalOffset >= MaxItemCount)
        {
            AssociatedObject.ScrollToVerticalOffset(JumpToItemCount);
        }
    }



    public double MaxItemCount
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaxItemCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxItemCountProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MaxItemCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxItemCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxItemCount", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerRestrictedScrollBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));





    public double JumpToItemCount
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(JumpToItemCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(JumpToItemCountProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for JumpToItemCount.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty JumpToItemCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("JumpToItemCount", typeof(double), typeof(ScrollViewerRestrictedScrollBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));


}
```

code from the xaml for using it (note I use values very close to 6, so it is not seen that there is a small jump in the vertical scroll bar) - this is part of the ListBox style:

```
<ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
  Template="{StaticResource landmarksScrollViewerControlTemplate}" >
      <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <ModuleBehaviors:ScrollViewerRestrictedScrollBehavior MaxItemCount="5.99" JumpToItemCount="5.97" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollViewer>
```